# Choosing a datastructure for working with small dataset

Tags: java, kotlin, data-structures, collections

I have a small set of Java POJOs, each them has several fields. I do not plan to add fields to them on the fly. Size of my set is small: it's not about some "bigdata", but rather about state of my application. I.e my data holder class looks like

```java
class MyObject
{
    private int a
    private String b
    private boolean c
}
```

I need some datastructure which can help me to make queries to this data by some field values: by a=5, b="abc" or c=true. For now it's OK to query by one fields only, i.e. I don't need complex queries.

A straightforward solution is to use maps:

```
Map<Integer, MyObject> aMap = new HashMap<>()
Map<String, MyObject> bMap = new HashMap<>()
Map<Boolean, MyObject> cMap = new HashMap<>()
```

The questions are:

1. Is there a way to make it better? Java version up to latest one.
2. Is there a way to make it better in Kotlin?
3. (optional requirement so far) What if I need to store it to make this collection survive application restart?

Comment: "better" in terms of performance or readable code? Question 3 is vague. You just save the data to a file or database--there are many ways to do that.

Comment: Define “small”. It’s not helpful to compare it to “bigdata”, just another undefined quantity.

Comment: You could get tens of millions of those records into memory, and the answer recommending the specification pattern would work well for querying. For persistence, you could just write the data to a CSV file that you read in at program startup. Assuming, of course, that you don't need to change the data while the program is running.

Comment: @Tenfour04, "better" in terms of readable code. 
As for persistence - I dont want to add a full-fledged relational DB because of 1 table. What are the options?

Comment: @Holger, "small" means at most several hundreds of objects of the size, which will not affect Java Heap significantly.

Comment: “several hundreds” is a size where even linear searches through a list would still have reasonable performance. A map from a value to a single object only makes sense if you assume that there can only be one object having this field value, which would be rather unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a separate data structure You can use a **Specification Pattern** to evaluate if an object satisfy a condition, using this pattern you can do any sort of combination and define even more complex rules

Here is an example (Kotlin version) :

```
import java.util.Objects

interface Specification<T> {
    fun isSatisfiedBy(obj: T): Boolean
}

class Or<T>(private val spec1: Specification<T>, private val spec2: Specification<T>) : Specification<T> {
    override fun isSatisfiedBy(obj: T) = spec1.isSatisfiedBy(obj) || spec2.isSatisfiedBy(obj)
}

class And<T>(private val spec1: Specification<T>, private val spec2: Specification<T>) : Specification<T> {
    override fun isSatisfiedBy(obj: T) = spec1.isSatisfiedBy(obj) && spec2.isSatisfiedBy(obj)
}

class FieldValue<T, V>(private val property: (T)->V, private val value: V): Specification<T> { 
    override fun isSatisfiedBy(obj: T) = property(obj) == value 
}
```

and you can use it like this :

```
fun main() {
    val myObjects: List<MyObject> = listOf(
    MyObject(1, "abc", true),
    MyObject(2, "def", false),
    MyObject(3, "abc", false),
    MyObject(4, "ghi", true),
    MyObject(5, "abc", true)
)
    
    // check the following condition a=5 OR (b=abc AND c = true)
    val spec: Specification<MyObject> = Or(
        FieldValue(MyObject::a, 5),
        And(
            FieldValue(MyObject::b, "abc"),
            FieldValue(MyObject::c, true)
        )
    )
    
    val results = myObjects.filter(spec::isSatisfiedBy)
}
```

Now this will filter on the fly your list so you need only to maintain your initial list of `MyObject`

Comment: It could also be implemented without reflection so you don't have to type property names as strings. `class FieldValue<T, V>(private val property: (T)->V, private val value: V): Specification<T> { override fun isSatisfiedBy(obj: T) = property(obj) == value }`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback , indeed this is more elegant , I edit my response to add it